# How to solve ReferenceError in knockout "with:" context

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

What is wrong with the following line?

```
 <div id="dialog" data-bind="with: SelectedText, dialog: {'autoOpen': false, 'title': textbatchTitle }, dialogVisible: $root.isMetadataDialogOpen "></div>
```

I get a console error: "ReferenceError: textbatchTitle is not defined"

At the same time earlier in the page this one is working perfectly:

```
<div id="Div1" class="textbatchdetails" data-bind="with: SelectedText" >
     <div>  
         <input type="text" name="textbatchTitle" data-bind="value: textbatchTitle, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"  />
     </div>
```

My dialog binding looks like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dialog = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};

        //do in a setTimeout, so the applyBindings doesn't bind twice from element being copied and moved to bottom
        setTimeout(function () {
            options.close = function () {
                allBindingsAccessor().dialogVisible(false);
            };

            $(element).dialog(ko.toJS(options));
        }, 0);

        //handle disposal (not strictly necessary in this scenario)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).dialog("destroy");
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var shouldBeOpen = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().dialogVisible),
            $el = $(element),
            dialog = $el.data("uiDialog") || $el.data("dialog"),
            options = valueAccessor();

        //don't call dialog methods before initilization
        if (dialog) {
            $el.dialog(shouldBeOpen ? "open" : "close");

            for (var key in options) {
                if (ko.isObservable(options[key])) {
                    $el.dialog("option", key, options[key]());
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: what properties does your object 'SelectedText' object contain? If it doesn't have the property textbatchTitle in it, then there's your problem.

Comment: It obviously must have as the send div works and displays the textbatchTitle, no?

Comment: From the Knockout documentation: "The with binding creates a new binding context, so that **descendant** elements are bound in the context of a specified object." In the case that works you are using descendant elements.

Answer (score 0):

Eric Brenden has basically given you the answer:

```
<div id="dialog" data-bind="with: SelectedText, dialog: {'autoOpen': false, 'title': textbatchTitle }, dialogVisible: $root.isMetadataDialogOpen ">
    <!-- INSIDE here, 'SelectedText' is the binding context, and 'textbatchTitle' works. However, the div with id = "dialog" ITSELF does not yet have the binding context 'SelectedText', instead its context is the parent of 'SelectedText'
</div>
```

Contrasting:

```
<div id="Div1" class="textbatchdetails" data-bind="with: SelectedText" >
     <!-- In here, just like above, the binding context is 'SelectedText'. So on this level, 'textbatchTitle' is fine
     <div>  
         <input type="text" name="textbatchTitle" data-bind="value: textbatchTitle, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"  />
     </div>
</div>
```

Solution 1:

```
<div data-bind="with: SelectedText">
    <div id="dialog" data-bind="dialog: {'autoOpen': false, 'title': textbatchTitle }, dialogVisible: $root.isMetadataDialogOpen "></div>
</div>
```

Solution 2: (SelectedText non-observable)

```
    <div id="dialog" data-bind="with: SelectedText, dialog: {'autoOpen': false, 'title': SelectedText.textbatchTitle }, dialogVisible: $root.isMetadataDialogOpen ">
```

Solution 3: (SelectedText observable)

```
    <div id="dialog" data-bind="with: SelectedText, dialog: {'autoOpen': false, 'title': SelectedText() ? SelectedText().textbatchTitle : '' }, dialogVisible: $root.isMetadataDialogOpen ">
```

And there are yet other ways to approach this (e.g. computed observable)
I'd go for solution 1.